# Passing of object array from parent to child component using @Input is not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

Hi in my project i tried to pass an object array from Parent component to child component (which is a custom modal) using @Input() but i am not getting the array in the child component , i tried almost all solutions in the stack overflow but i couldn't figure out the mistake. It may be a simple mistake , but i can't resolve the problem.

The class is

```
export class Fnames
{
      public Fname: string;   
      constructor(Fname: string)
        {
            this.Fname = Fname;
        }

}
```

The object array in perent component is

```
   fnames : Fnames [] = [];
```

The object array in child component is

```
  @Input() fname : Fnames [] =[];
```

The html of perent component is

```
 <app-fname-modal [fname]="fnames"  [(visible)]="fpermission">
     <p *ngFor=" let tmp of fname"> {{tmp.Fname}} </p>
 </app-fname-modal>
```

The html of child component(which is a modal) is

```
<div [@dialog] *ngIf="visible" class="dialog">
    <p *ngFor="let tmp of students">{{tmp.Fname}}</p>
    <!-- <h1>Hi jins it is began to work!</h1> -->
    <button *ngIf="closable" (click)="close()" aria-label="Close" 
     class="dialog__close-btn">X</button>
</div>
```

**Error:**

```
 Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object HTMLInputElement]' of type 'object'.
 NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with normally it works. I removed a few items from your code to go fast, but you can put them back according to what you want to do.

---

**fnames.ts**

```
export class Fnames
{
      public fname: string;   
      constructor(fname: string)
        {
            this.fname = fname;
        }

}
```

---

**parent TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Fnames } from './fnames'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public fnames : Fnames [] = [];

  constructor(){
    for(let i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
      let foo: Fnames = new Fnames(`fooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo${i}`)
      this.fnames[i] = foo;
    }
  }

}
```

---

**parent HTML**

```
<app-fname-modal [fnames]="fnames" >
</app-fname-modal>
```

---

**child TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'; import { Fnames } from '../fnames'

@Component({ selector: 'app-fname-modal', templateUrl: './fname-modal.component.html', styleUrls: ['./fname-modal.component.css'] }) export class FnameModalComponent implements OnInit { @Input() fnames : Fnames [] =[]; public students: String[] = new Array();

constructor() { for(let i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){ let student = max${i} this.students[i] = student; } }

ngOnInit() { }

}
```

---

**child HTML**

```
<div class="dialog">
  <div *ngFor="let student of students">
      <p>{{student}} : </p>
      <p *ngFor="let tmp of fnames">{{tmp.fname}}</p>
    </div>
  <!-- <h1>Hi jins it is began to work!</h1> -->
  <button aria-label="Close" 
   class="dialog__close-btn">X</button>
</div>
```